# add static css file with express.js

Tags: css, express, sass

I have a .css file generated with koala from a .scss file and I added it in my index.html. The page won't serve my file and I learned that its due to me not adding the file on my express server as static. I tried to follow the different options listed on the express server documentation http://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html:

1)

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

as I used:

```
app.use(express.static('styles/css'));
```

2)

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

as I used:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('styles/css'));
```

3)

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

as I used:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/styles/css'));
```

But non is working I tried different combinations and i must have been doing something wrong.

This is my folder path:

```
project
  src
   styles
      bower_components
      css
         app.css
      sass
         app.sass
   app.js
   index.html
  package.json
  server.js
  webpack.config.js
```

This is my express server.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config');

const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);
const middleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: { colors: true },
});

app.use(middleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const renderHtml = () => middleware.fileSystem
    .readFileSync(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'))
    .toString();
  res.send(renderHtml());
});

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/styles/css')))

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000');
});
```

I need to know in this particular example how should I use the express static line to make it work. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: My webpack.config file looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your `app.get('*' ...)` is the culprit. Since you use the wildcard `*` it matches every possible URL.

And since you put `app.use('/static', ...)` after that, I think it's gonna be ignored.

My two cents:

- Try putting `app.static(...)` *before* `app.get('*', ...)`.
- If you use `app.static('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/styles/css')))` then in your HTML your `<link>` tag should look like: `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/your-css-file.css' type='text/css'>`
- Otherwise simply use `app.use(express.static(__dirname))` and in your HTML you should have `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles/css/your-css-file.css' type='text/css'>`

Overall, keep in mind that the order in which you declare your middlewares with `app.use(...)` matters.